# Unable to start a service on boot (Linux Mint 19.3)

Tags: linux-mint, services, autostart

I'm trying to setup a service to run on startup. I've searched for hours and tried multiple methods but none have been fruitful.

My machine is running on `linux mint 19.3`

The service I'm trying to start on boot is `lizardfs-chunkserver.service`

I've tried:

```
sudo update-rc.d lizardfs-chinkserver defaults
```

and

```
sudo systemctl enable lizardfs-chunkserver.service
```

But eveytime I reboot the service still doesn't start. I check the status of the service with:

```
service --status-all
```

I've also tried to install `sysv-rc-conf` with `sudo apt-get install sysv-rc-conf` but the package doesn't seem to exist for `Mint 19.3`.
I've checked for errors in `journalctl` but I don't get errors. Help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I think the issue has to do with the `lizardfs-chunkserver`, not sure why it just won't autostart but `lizardfs-master` autostarts fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the name of the service right?

sudo systemctl enable SERVICE **should** work

Comment: Also, the .service isn't required

Comment: Yeah, I'm 100% sure. I think it has something to do with ```Mint 19.3``` because I tried the same thing on Mint 20 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Hmm, odd... I'm on Mint 19.3 on my laptop (and Mint 20 on my desktop). I could reproduce and get back to you, I'll look into it... Good luck, let us know how it goes :)

Comment: I think it has to do with the service. I tried to autostart ```lizardfs-master``` and it worked but ```lizardfs-chunkserver``` did not like it at all.